# C++ Text adventure game - Make words upper case

Tags: c++, text, vector, adventure

Basically, i'm following this tutorial : http://cplussplussatplay.blogspot.com.cy/2012/11/text-adventure-games-c-part-1.html

I have understood everything up to now except from this:

```
// Make words upper case
// Right here is where the functions from cctype are used
    for(i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < words.at(i).size(); j++)
        {
            if(islower(words.at(i).at(j)))
            {
                words.at(i).at(j) = toupper(words.at(i).at(j));
            }
        }
    }
```

At this point, we have a words vector which is full of characters. 
I don't understand the need of two for loops, nor this words.at(i).at(j)).
Is it a 2D vector or something?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : Thank you all very much for your help! I have understood it now! This is the first time using Stack Overflow and i'm loving it so far! :)

One more thing, another question has arised!

```
string sub_str;
vector words;
char search = ' ';



    // Clear out any blanks
    // I work backwords through the vectors here as a cheat not to       invalidate the iterator
    for(i = words.size() - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if(words.at(i) == "")
        {
            words.erase(words.begin() + i);
        }
```

1. What does the second comment mean?

2.How can there be blanks in the vector? The first loops according to the creator clears out any blanks.
This is the code previously :

```
for(i = 0; i < Cmd.size(); i++)
    {
        if(Cmd.at(i) != search)
        {
            sub_str.insert(sub_str.end(), Cmd.at(i));
        }
        if(i == Cmd.size() - 1)
        {
            words.push_back(sub_str);
            sub_str.clear();
        }
        if(Cmd.at(i) == search)
        {
            words.push_back(sub_str);
            sub_str.clear();
        }
    }
```

Thanks again!

Comment: `vector words;` hmmm, bad tutorial.

Comment: First loop is over words. The second one is over characters in a word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add comments to walk through the code:

```
// Make words upper case
// Right here is where the functions from cctype are used
for(i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) // for each word in the vector "words"
{
    for(j = 0; j < words.at(i).size(); j++) // for each character in the word "words[i]"
    {
        if(islower(words.at(i).at(j)))      // if the character is lower case...
        {
            words.at(i).at(j) = toupper(words.at(i).at(j)); // ...make upper case
        }
    }
}
```

So outer loop iterates over each word, and then inner loop iterates over each character of the current word, and changes it to upper case, if it is a lower case character.

I believe it is slightly more efficient to have the character changing line as:

```
words.at(i).at(i) -= 32; // ...make upper case
```

Which doesn't require function calling: jump, push and pop machine instructions to call `toupper()`. Just allow for immediate addressing within the same function (and therefore stack frame).

Comment: how is that supposed to be "one less access"? In both cases the value has to be read and then a new value is assigned

Answer (score 1):

`i` is the index of a certain word. `j` is the index of a certain character.
The algorithm cycles through each `char` of a word and then processes the next word.

Answer (score 1):

The first loop itterate trough your `word` vector (from the first word to the last one at position `word.size - 1`) then the second loop go trough all the word charaters.  If the character at the position `j` of the word at position `i` is lower case, then make it upper case

Comment: btw I cantt figure why you use function like "at(i)" if word is only an array